# How to place an image and text under it, side by side using HTML and css?

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve something like this:

```
|-----------|     |-----------|     |-----------|
|           |     |           |     |           | 
|  image    |     |  image    |     |  image    |
|           |     |           |     |           |
|-----------|     |-----------|     |-----------|
   image 1           image 2           image 3
```

There should be images side by side and also there should be description about these images under each image.
I tried placing each image under its own "div" tag and also used display:inline property of css but above format is not getting displayed.

Comment: Try this example i made for you http://jsfiddle.net/hN4PM/

Comment: There are dozens of ways to do that. The choice between them depends on many things—you could write a book on this. So this is really too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

## <kbd>J[sFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HdvNc/1/)</kbd>

#### CSS

```
.container{
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}
img{
    width: 150px;
    height:150px;
    float: left;
}
.text{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 introduced the [`figure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure) element that is used to connect an image with its caption with [`figcaption`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption).

```
<figure>
    <img src="path/to/your/image" width="150px" height="150px" />
    <figcaption>First image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

To get the figures side by side use the css

```
figure {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and to center the text below the image use

```
figcaption {
    text-align: center;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/TSWND/1/ for an example with 3 dummy images

Answer (score 0):

you need to create div container with two children: div wher you have img and another div with text. Add them proper width and  `float: left.` That should help

EDIT: fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4mrg/)

Comment: Can I have the code for that? I have trying this for a few hours but without any result.

Answer (score 0):

use div

```
display:block;
float:left;
```

Answer (score 0):

use float :left in css in middle DIV

```
<div>

   <div> image code</div>// <-- use here float left
   <div> discription code </div>//<-- use here float left
</div
```

Answer (score 0):

U can also use

```
<figure>
<img src="">
<legend></legend>
</figure>
```

Use this structure to contain your elements, tha float each figure element to the right or left and than  add div with clear:both style.

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution:

```
<style type="text/css">
   #container{
   height:100%;
   width: 100px; 
}
</script
<body>
<div id="container">
<img id="a" src="" height="100" width="100" ></img><br /><p> this is text1</p><br />
<img id="b" src="" height="100" width="100" ></img><br /><p> this is text2</p><br />
<img id="c" src="" height="100" width="100" ></img><br /><p> this is text3</p><br />
<img id="d" src="" height="100" width="100" ></img><br /><p> this is text4</p><br />
</div>
</body
```

in src you put your image source, i have left blank and remember the width of your image should not exceed from the width of container.